# Is there anything wrong with using dispatch_once in layoutSubviews?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm setting up a custom UIButton and need to add a bunch of views as subviews only once.
To keep my implementation file slim, and to refrain from setting up all the views in `initWithFrame:` only to have someone do something like `button = [[Button alloc] init]; button.frame = someFrame;`, I'm doing the following;

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [self setupViews];
    });
}

- (void)setupViews
{
    // add all subviews here
}
```

It all looks fine to me; I am just wondering if I'm doing something that's not recommended?
To expand this question even further, is it safe to have `dispatch_once` inside a method that's going to be called constantly? (e.g. View setup code inside `viewDidAppear`).

Comment: Why not use `viewDidLoad` for this setup?

Comment: How many instances do you have?

Comment: @bdesham, can't use viewDidLoad as it's a subclassed UIButton.

Comment: @Wain I plan to have one instance but layoutSubviews will be called pretty often.

Comment: If you have multiple instances in the future you could get very confused. Probably better to have a `BOOL` instance variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for the first instance of your button.  Any other instances won't perform the `dispatch_once` block.

[`dispatch_once`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_once) only gets called if onceToken is NULL, so this won't get called per-instance of your object, as `onceToken` is persisted across instances.

`[object layoutSubviews]`

Calls the block, but then...

`[object2 layoutSubviews]`

does not call the block.

---

```
@interface TestObject : NSObject

- (void)log;

@end


@implementation TestObject

- (void)log {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSLog(@"Called once");

    });
}

@end


TestObject *ob1 = [[TestObject alloc] init];
TestObject *ob2 = [[TestObject alloc] init];

[ob1 log];
[ob2 log];
```

`2013-12-16 11:59:34.760 test[43445:70b] Called once`

That's all the output you get.  Because `ob1` has already run, `obj2` sees the `onceToken` has already performed and won't perform it a second time.

Comment: On further thought, the more I look at it, the more I feel like I should chuck this pattern out the window. If I want to give the user the freedom to remove subviews, it's not going to be possible to add them back because of the dispatch_once.

Comment: I usually do [lazy loading on properties](https://gist.github.com/skylarsch/7994593).  Then in the init, you can set background color or something of the like.

Answer (score 4):

`layoutSubviews` shouldn't be used to add the subviews, since it's called multiple times (on rotation, status bar height change, etc.)

Instead, add your subviews in your UIView subclass's `init` method, and set their frames in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Hi Aaron, that's what I used to do but I wanted to break away from using the initializers for this one. Shouldn't dispatch_once inside layoutSubviews work similar to a singleton pattern under ARC? We call the shared instance initializer for a singleton multiple times and it contains a dispatch_once... I figured doing the same with layoutSubviews would be the same thing.

Comment: Since all UI work should be done on the main thread, you don't need `dispatch_once` for this.  You can just use `if (!someSubview)`.  But why "break away from using the initializers for this one" when this is exactly what initializers are for?

Comment: I figured that for UIButton, some can use any one out of initWithFrame, init and buttonWithTitle. I was experimenting with viable alternatives to do it outside the init to avoid customizing all three.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use layoutSubviews in order to setup your views frames. If are you planning to add subviews a good place to do this task is viewDidLoad Method or awakeFromNib.

Comment: Unfortunately since this is a UIButton subclass and I'm not using an IB file for this one, neither one of those methods apply. I will, however try to figure out a different way of doing this. My only concern is that I want to move away from a custom initializer on this one. That leaves developers the freedom to use any initializer they want for the button (initWithFrame, init, buttonWithTitle, etc).

Comment: If is a subclass button, you only need to add all the subviews on the init method.